# Is it valid to use undefined as a last operand of OR operator in order to assign value?

Tags: javascript

Is it valid to write code below in order to get `undefined` (not `false`) in the result in any circumstances when the first operand is falsy? Regardless of JavaScript version and regardless of the browser and its version.

```
let someFalsyValue = "";
let result = someFalsyValue || undefined;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is safe.

[logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) returns the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value or the last truthy/falsy value.

It has been in the standard of the very first version of [ECMA-262, 1st edition, June 1997](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) in chapter *11.11 Binary logical operators*.

Answer (score 2):

It is, and has always been, reliable to use the `||` operator in this way.

The global `undefined` property, (which contrary to the belief of many JS users, is not a special literal defined in the language syntax like `null`) has a more complex history. In older browsers, there was no guarantee that the value of `window.undefined` was actually, well, undefined, as any code could set it. Therefore it was customary to use the `void` operator instead, or work inside the scope of a function where one of the arguments was known to be unspecified by the caller, and thus have the value undefined.